# Can't access property in push method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, momentjs

I've got a simple function within an angular Directive using momentjs. It builds the week for a calendar. I'm try to set unavailability dates for bookings.

Using Chrome console I thought I fixed the issue using: `indexOf();`

The problem I have is when I move the code in inside the push method it returns `date is undefined (.date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`:

```
function _buildWeek(date, month) {

            var days = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

                    days.push({
                        name: date.format("dd").substring(0, 1),
                        number: date.date(),
                        isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
                        isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day"),
                        date: date,
                        unavailable: dealerUnAvailabilityDates[0].daysOff.indexOf(days[days.length-1].date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) !== -1
                    });

                    date = date.clone();
                    date.add(1, "d");


                }

                console.log(days);


            return days;
        }
```

I'm guessing the issue is 'date' is part of the object, so you can't use it until the object has been created. It's trying to use itself.\

How can I fix this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `days[days.length - 1]` is not yet populated by the time you try to use it in each iteration. However, you can safely use `date` object itself as it's what you want anyway:

```
var days = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    days.push({
        name: date.format("dd").substring(0, 1),
        number: date.date(),
        isCurrentMonth: date.month() === month.month(),
        isToday: date.isSame(new Date(), "day"),
        date: date,
        unavailable: dealerUnAvailabilityDates[0].daysOff.indexOf(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) !== -1
    });                                // use date directly here --^ 

    date = date.clone();
    date.add(1, "d");
}
```